# How can i optimize the below query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance, sql-tuning

I have a table like this.

```
_id (integer)
event_name(varchar(20))
event_date(timestamp)
```

Here is some sample data given below.

---

```
ID         event_date                          event_name
101        2013-04-24 18:33:37.694818          event_A
102        2013-04-24 20:34:37.000000          event_B
103        2013-04-24 20:40:37.000000          event_A
104        2013-04-25 01:00:00.694818          event_B
105        2013-04-25 12:00:15.694818          event_A
```

I need the data from above table in below format.

```
Date          count_eventA                       count_eventB
2013-04-24    2                                   1
2013-04-25    1                                   1
```

hence basically in need the count of each event on each date.

I have tried below query for getting the desired result.

```
SELECT A.date1 AS Date ,
       A.count1 AS count_eventA,
       B.count2 AS count_eventB,
           FROM
           (SELECT count(event_name)AS count1,
            event_date::date AS date1
            FROM tblname
            WHERE event_name='event_A'
            GROUP BY (event_date::date))AS A 
           LEFT JOIN
           (SELECT count(event_name)AS count1,
            event_date::date AS date1
            FROM tblname
            WHERE event_name='event_B'
            GROUP BY (event_date::date))AS B ON A.date1=B.date2
```

Can someone please suggest me to find out a better and optimized query? , or I am following a good approach .

Comment: is there will be only two event?

Comment: There can be more than 2 events , but right now I need to care for only 2 event.

Comment: PostgreSQL version? `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`? See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: @CraigRinger .. PostgreSQL 9.0.0.

Comment: @Anant 9.0.0 ? Well, that won't help. http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/ . The current patch release is 9.0.13; you're missing at least one index corruption bug fix and a **major** security bug fix per http://www.postgresql.org/support/security/faq/2013-04-04/ . You're missing two and a half years worth of patches...

Comment: @CraigRinger . thanks . but i am working on local machine, and just want to get more efficient query? on live server i guess  the version is updated..

Comment: @Anant Best to use the same version on local and live, otherwise you're not testing in the same environment you're deploying to. Badness results.

Comment: @CraigRinger ..thanks. I will synchronize the local and live postgres version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something on this lines should work:

```
select event_date::date AS Date ,
        count_eventA = sum(case when event_name = 'event_A' then 1 else 0 end),
     count_eventB = sum(case when event_name = 'event_B' then 1 else 0 end)
from tblname
GROUP BY (event_date::date))
```

If you have more events you only need to add more `sum(case)` lines :)

The DBEngine only runs through the table once to give you the totals, independiently of the number of the events you want to count: when you have a high rowcount you will observe significant delay with the original query. Should I add this to my answer, you think

Comment: can you please explain little more , how this would be the better approach?

Comment: The DBEngine only runs through the table once to give you the totals, independiently of the number of the events you want to count: when you have a high rowcount you will observe significant delay with the original query. Should I add this to my answer, you think?

Comment: thanks @Zelloss .. for the nice answer !! and yes , it would be better if you add the above description in the answers also.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler (and cleaner) than the case syntax:

```
select
    event_date::date as Date,
    count(event_name = 'event_A' or null) count_eventA,
    count(event_name = 'event_B' or null) count_eventB
from t
group by 1
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.  Can you please explain in your answer, when it is the matter of performance, how above query works better than "CASE Syntax query" ?

Comment: @Anant I guess the performance will be very similar if not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for [PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in sql check below example is very handy

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/

Comment: Not on PostgreSQL they're not, as those commands do not exist.